# Authentication to Google API: Do Javascript in page and server backend need different identities?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-api

I am trying to develop an application with client and server parts that serves in part as an alternative interface to Google Drive. The idea is to have the server list particular files from the Google Drive and make them available for download by the user.

I have implemented the server listing part on Google App Engine, but I am now working on the download part on the client. By providing the `downloadUrl` to the user on the web page, the user should be able to download the file, assuming they authenticate hence the question:

Do I need to register the web application as a separate application that uses the [Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/dev/dev_jscript) with separate `client_id` and other identifiers, or should it use the same security settings as the App Engine application server-side?